# Exact fetch returns more than requested

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to write a stored procedure.I need to fetch the faculty id by using an id.The ids are unique but yet when I try to fetch the facultyid I get the error:exact fetch returns more than requested rows.

I have checked many similar questions on oracle community and stack overflow but did not get any proper answers

My stored procedure is as follows;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE updateStatus(id IN int)

IS  

facid varchar2(10);

total_count int;

accepted_count int;

rejected_count int;

design varchar2(25);

BEGIN

    SELECT facultyid INTO facid FROM TEMP_LEAVE_DETAILS WHERE id=id;

    SELECT design INTO design FROM FACULTY WHERE facultyid=facid;

    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO total_count FROM CLASS_ADJUST WHERE id=id;

    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO accepted_count FROM CLASS_ADJUST WHERE id=id AND 

     accepted='Accepted';

    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO rejected_count FROM CLASS_ADJUST WHERE id=id AND 

     accepted='Rejected';

    IF(total_count=accepted_count) THEN

        IF design='hod' THEN

            UPDATE TEMP_LEAVE_DETAILS SET appr_by='Principal' WHERE id=id;

        ELSE

            UPDATE TEMP_LEAVE_DETAILS SET appr_by='HOD' WHERE id=id;

        END IF;

    END IF;

END;
```

I get this error when I execute the procedure:

> BEGIN UPDATESTATUS(23); END;
>
> *
>
> ERROR at line 1:
>
> ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
>
> ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.UPDATESTATUS", line 9
>
> ORA-06512: at line 1

Please help me solve this error by some solution and if possible, explaination why this doesn't work
Thanks in advance

Comment: How many rows do the first two queries return? More than 1 each?

Comment: Rename your parameter, then you won't have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT facultyid INTO facid FROM TEMP_LEAVE_DETAILS WHERE id=id;
```

I haven't used oracle, but in sql server and MySQL this query returns all `facultyid` (except where id is null) because `id=id` is always true unless `id` is null, because `null=null` returns `false`.

Since `facid` is a `varchar(10)` it expects only one row. You want to use a different condition in the `where` clause, by changing the name of the parameter id.

Also, a similar problem may occur in the second query in case there are a lot of rows that match `facid`

Comment: Happy to help :D
Since you are new to stackoverflow, I encourage you to upvote and/or accept the answers that you find helpful, so that they are more easily noticeable to other users who may face similar problems in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is:

```
where id = id
```

This will return all non-`NULL` values of `id`.

You need to distinguish columns from parameters.  I would write this code as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE updateStatus (
    in_id IN int
) AS  
    v_facid varchar2(10);
    v_total_count int;
    v_accepted_count int;
    v_rejected_count int;
    v_design varchar2(25);
BEGIN
    SELECT facultyid INTO facid
    FROM TEMP_LEAVE_DETAILS tld
    WHERE tld.id = in_id;

    . . .
```